# Should Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman get its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

This may seem a trivially obvious, but I wasn't quite sure.  I was writing [another Walter M. Miller, Jr. question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258891/is-the-original-incomplete-manuscript-of-saint-leibowitz-and-the-wild-horse-wom) for the monthly theme just know, but the question was actually about *Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman*, rather than *A Canticle for Leibowitz*.  The current tag guidance for [a-canticle-for-leibowitz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-canticle-for-leibowitz) says:

> Published in 1960, A Canticle for Leibowitz is a post-apocalyptic novel from Walter M. Miller. It is widely considered one of the "classics" of science-fiction. The tag should be used for questions about the story, background, or adaptations.

Long version:

> Set in the Earth's future, following a nuclear conflict that left the surface of the planet devastated, and our cultures, societies, and technology scattered, Walter M. Miller's *A Canticle for Leibowitz* is told in three parts, covering three separate time periods and sets of characters.
>
> Miller paints a grim depiction of mankind and our cyclical relationship with technology and conflict, interwoven with elements of issues of religion and morality.
>
> Parts of the story have been adapted for radio or as dramatizations, and a lesser-known sequel, *Saint Leibowitz and the Wild Horse Woman*, was written by Miller many years later.

So the sequel is mentioned in the long description, but the short tag guidance only says to use [a-canticle-for-leibowitz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-canticle-for-leibowitz) for "story, background, or adaptations."  It seems like we can add mention of the sequel there, or make a new tag, treating *A Canticle for Leibowitz* as essentially the name of the two-book series.  What do people think?

Answer (score 3):

### Use the existing tag to cover *Saint Leibowitz*.

Have there ever been any prior questions about *Saint Leibowitz*? Probably not many if that answer is even yes.

It seems like since it takes place in same universe, [a-canticle-for-leibowitz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-canticle-for-leibowitz) adhering to its long form description may be the best solution; but in this case because it is a recognized and intended sequel / derivative work to *Canticle*.